# Django url error"NoReverseMatch at /2/ipd/"

Tags: python, django

I am having form which creates Ipd and Ipd model is created using patient model with one to many relationship, and I am already having one table with patient list in urls.
I am trying to create the list of all Ipd that are created using form, I am trying to redirect the form page to Idp list after I submit for Ipd form but ending with this error "NoReverseMatch at /1/ipd/",

One thing I want to clear is each Ipd is having unique id and Ipd is created from patient with one to many relationship which also have another unique id , the number which is in the error is patient id

views.py

```py
@login_required
def ipd(request, patient_id):


    object = get_object_or_404(Patient,pk=patient_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        formtwo = IpdForm(request.POST)
        if formtwo.is_valid() :
            instance = formtwo.save(commit=False) 
            instance.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('ipd_list', args=[patient_id]))
        else:
            return HttpResponse(formtwo.errors) 
    else:
        formtwo = IpdForm()

    return render(request, 'newipd.html', {'object':object, 'form2': formtwo})

@login_required
def ipd_list(request):

    ipdlist = Ipd.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'Ipdlist.html', {'ipd': ipdlist })
```

urls.py

```py
re_path(r'^$', my_patient.index, name='home'),      <-- patient list-->
re_path(r'^(?P<patient_id>\d+)/ipd/$', my_patient.ipd, name='ipd'),
path(r'^ipdlist/', my_patient.ipd_list,name='ipdlist' ),
```

Template

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="{% url 'ipdlist' %}" ><span class="title">Indoor Patient Department</span></a></li>
</ul>

########
in ipdform

<form class="col s12" role="form" action="{% url 'ipd_list' 'patient_id' %}" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data"> {% csrf_token %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to redirect user to `ipdlist` url instead with patameters. As this is a list method you shouldn't do that. You need to change:

```py
@login_required
def ipd(request, patient_id):


    object = get_object_or_404(Patient,pk=patient_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        formtwo = IpdForm(request.POST)
        if formtwo.is_valid() :
            instance = formtwo.save(commit=False) 
            instance.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('ipd_list'))
        else:
            return HttpResponse(formtwo.errors) 
    else:
        formtwo = IpdForm()

    return render(request, 'newipd.html', {'object':object, 'form2': formtwo})

@login_required
def ipd_list(request):

    ipdlist = Ipd.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'Ipdlist.html', {'ipd': ipdlist })
```

Comment: I want to display the list of user(ipd) that are created after submitting ipd form

Comment: But why do you specify the ```patient_id``` as an argument then?

Comment: Still not working, Now not even rendering Ipd Form, Error "Reverse for 'ipd_list' not found. 'ipd_list' is not a valid view function or pattern name. "

Comment: NoReverseMatch at /2/ipd/
Reverse for 'ipd_list' not found. 'ipd_list' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: I have changed ```ipd_list``` to ```ipdlist``` in my answer. You shouldnt be using ```ipd_list``` anymore. Please make sure you adapt my answer completely.

Comment: I've put the whole view class for you, please use that.

Comment: make sure your ```ipdlist.html``` is under ```your_app/templates/ipdlist/Ipdlist.html```

Comment: @VickyRathod In somewhere, you are using 'ipd_detail'. You need to change it to 'ipd' because that is the name you defined for your detail request in your ```urls.py```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove `args=[patiend_id]` since you are returning to the ipd_list

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('ipd_list'))
```

Comment: Still not working, Now not even rendering Ipd Form, Error  "Reverse for 'ipd_list' not found. 'ipd_list' is not a valid view function or pattern name. "

Comment: i didn't see any url name defined with `ipd_list` in your urls.I think its `ipdlist`.Do `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('ipdlist'))`

Comment: `action="{% url 'ipd_list' 'patient_id' %}` what is this for since you don't have any url with `ipd_list`